# How to kill one child process when the parent constantly changes the child PID and i use more than one child with the same name?

Tags: bash, pid

I have a Parent script that executes 5 other children. All the 5 children have the exact same name and the PID is constantly changing for each one of them. It is a script for some hardware tests. I don't want to use 5 different scripts due to constant updates and changes. (it will mean 5 times the writing).

In case of some failure I need to kill exactly one of those 5 child processes. Is there any way to force the gnome from changing the PID ? Or forcing a background process to work with a certain PID ?

Comment: Pid can't change after process has started. Do you mean that they have different pids everytime you start the parent script?

Comment: In the child process i have some sleeps and user interactions when i don't see the process anymore, and after that i see a new PID for the child process.

Comment: Thats a different process then.

Comment: @DragosN. - for debugging, add something like `date "+[%F %T] pid=$$" >>/tmp/debuglog` as one of the first lines of your child script. Then every time a new log line is added to `/tmp/debuglog`, you can be certain that the child script has been relaunched. If you need help with the scripts, please include the scripts in your question. It's difficult to help with your code without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Process ID is assigned by the operating system when a new process is launched. As far as I'm aware there's no way to control the ID which is used.

It sounds like your parent script launches the same child script five times. I suggest modifying your parent script to use trigger files to prevent the launching of each child process:

```
if [ ! -f /wherever/trigger_file_1 ] ; then
  # Launch child process #1 here
fi

if [ ! -f /wherever/trigger_file_2 ] ; then
  # Launch child process #2 here
fi

if [ ! -f /wherever/trigger_file_3 ] ; then
  # Launch child process #3 here
fi

if [ ! -f /wherever/trigger_file_4 ] ; then
  # Launch child process #4 here
fi

if [ ! -f /wherever/trigger_file_5 ] ; then
  # Launch child process #5 here
fi
```

When, for example, you decide that you need to prevent child process #3 from running you can do the following from any terminal:

```
touch /wherever/trigger_file_3
```

and child process #3 will no longer be launched. When you decide that you want to allow child process #3 to run all you need to do is

```
rm /wherever/trigger_file_3
```

and that child process will now be launched normally.

Best of luck.

Comment: I foud out that i use not getting the PID of the child process, but instead the PID of the gnome terminal. I was using $! and this was returning the PID of last background process, witch was not of the child i was starting in background. The final solution was to write the PID with $$ of the child, in an other file and the grep it from there in case i need to kill it from the parent script. Thank you very much for help.